# Insert Row(child) in table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table containing 4 main rows and one (expand or collapse) button.On click of (expand or collapse) button i want to insert one more row in middle of all rows(which result in total 8 rows) by iterating the table rows.How to do this using Javascript?See the image below.Any suggestion.

[image]

This is the code i have return on click of Expand or Collapse button,

```
  jQuery('#btnId').click(function() {
            var that = this;
            $("#example tbody tr").each(function(i) {                   
                //what code need to add here
            });
        });
```

Comment: Google "jquery insert row into table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact, that you haven't provided a code example, I only can suggest one way to achieve this.

You can determine the row above the row you'll want to insert by an id on the `tr` or by a css selector like `:nth-of-type(4)` for example.

After that, you can use this row as jquery element (example: `$("tr#yourrow")`) and append a row after it using `append()`.

Example: `$("tr#yourrow").append("<tr>... your row definition ...</tr>")`

Based on the updated question:

```
jQuery('#btnId').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $("#example tbody tr").each(function(i, object) {                   
        $(object).after("<tr>... your row definition ...</tr>")
    });
});
```

The row definition should be done by yourself. I don't know the logic behind the iteration in your case. But I think you'll get it. :)

Comment: @lonic thanks for your reply..i have added the code sample for button click..can tell me how to insert row

Comment: need to iterate table and insert new row next to employee id 03040 again next to empid 030150 one more row so on..

Comment: I've added another example

Comment: Thanks lonic..i tried but its getting added as column next to Address Colum

Comment: Instead of adding as new row its adding as new column

Comment: Thanks lonic..instead of append("<tr>... your row definition ...</tr>") to used after("<tr>... your row definition ...</tr>") method... (+1) up

Comment: Ah thanks. I think I've got your question wrong. :-D Thanks for the edit. :-)